# Java Regex (регулярные выражения)

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Как правильно использовать регулярные выражения в Java?
Например, в меня есть строка "5*6/9+M5"
мне нужно что бы строка разделилась  на строки "5","6","7","M5".
Использовал так

```
String value[] = val.split("[/][*][-][+]");
```

Как-то ничего не заработало.

Так же есть такой способ

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[/][*][-][+]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
```

Но я не понимаю, что делать далее.
Помогите, кто может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[/][*][-][+]
```

соответствует тексту:

```
/*-+
```

именно так - четыре символа один за другим.
Рекомендую прочитать основы регулярных выражения в части касающейся символьных классов.
Это позволит самостоятельно прийти к такому решению проблемы:

```
String[] value = val.split("[/*+-]");
```

Answer (score 4):

В паттерне у `split` достаточно на писать `[/*+-]`, то есть найти один любой символ, представленный в наборе. А так как должен вернуться массив, то нужно его складывать не в `String value`, а в `String[] value`

```
String testy = "5*6/999+M5";
String[] value = testy.split("[/*+-]");

for (String s : value) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

выведет

```
5
6
999
M5
```

http://ideone.com/gV5Zlq

---

C Pattern/Matcher все будет посложнее.
Сам паттерн будет выглядеть как-то так: `[^/*+-]+`, то есть найти символы 1 или более, которые не `/` и не `*` и не `+` и не `-`;

```
String testy = "5*6/9+M5";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^/*+-]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(testy);
```

Однако этого мало. Чтоб все эти совпадения найти и куда запихать, надо воспользоваться методом `find()` - он возвращает true, если шаблон совпадает с любой частью текста.

После успешного сопоставления, `m.start()` вернет индекс первого символа, совпавшего и `m.end()` вернет индекс последнего совпавшего символа, плюс один.

```
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(testy.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
}
```

http://ideone.com/HtxN8R

Можете это все добавить в какой-нибудь `ArrayList` или еще куда, по желанию.

---

И в зависимости от того, будут ли между числами и знаками пробелы или еще что - нужно будет подкорректировать регулярки.